# Without Trial and Error or a dental professional, how can you determine your size of Interdental Brush?

Tags: health

How can you determine by yourself  which size of  [TePe Interdental Brushes](http://tepecanada.com/consumers_en/tepe-interdental-brushes-original/) fits (your [Interproximal Space](http://www.dentaid.com/en/interproximal-cleaning))?

Disregard and pretermit:

1. Trial and Error (ie: randomly selecting a size, and then purchasing a pack of these brushes)
2. or seeing the dental professional (e.g. dentist, oral hygienist) for him/her to determine the size (to avert costs).

Comment: For something so specialised, it may be better to consult your dentist/oral hygienist/dental specialist.

Answer (score 2):

I use the same brand, so I can give you a rough rule of thumb, assuming you've used dental floss in the past. If floss tends to break or shred, or you find that some floss is too thick to use comfortably, try the blue or pink size. I suggest you get a pack of both, because some the spaces between your teeth will be wider, some narrower. Otherwise, I'd try the orange or red.

Alternatively, I have seen packs with a brush in each size (these packs aren't listed on the page you linked to, but I have seen them in stores). Your teeth are unlikely to be all exactly the same distance apart, so you'll probably be able to use at least three of the brush sizes in the pack. And the remaining brushes may come in useful for cleaning other things besides teeth. So this is a fairly cost-effective way to find out your size.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, it is an indirect one. Getting the answer from a professional need not be costly.

Many dental professionals will probably see you for a consultation. Sometimes walk-in clinics will see you and sometimes you can make an appointment.

While I haven't tried it, I'm reasonably sure that such a question will be answered without charge by a dentist or a dental hygienist. I've had free consultations and second opinions.

Many hospitals have dental aid available. Stopping in to get such preventative information is part of wellness regime that no health care unit could refuse. They probably have samples to give away.

Every dental care unit I have ever visited has bags and boxes of samples donated by manufacturers to give away. They are not for resale. A dentist or dental hygienist will probably give you a small bag of different brushes, floss, and scrapers to find one that suits your regime and mouth.

Contact product manufacturers directly and ask for samples. They will probably fall all over themselves to please such an aware and cautious person. Their names and addresses are on the packaging in a well-stocked pharmacy or on the Internet.